# Rails 5: can't access update method in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to update an attribute with a single button like so:

```
<%= link_to loan_product, lead_path(@lead, lead: { loan_product: loan_product }, method: :patch) %>
```

The params come through just fine, but `lead_path` only accesses the `show` method of the controller and not the `update` one *despite* the `method` being set to *either* `:patch` or `:put`, and because of that the attribute isn't updated.

How can I point this `link_to` to the default `update` method in the controller? I'm just rocking default resources in `routes.rb`, i.e., `resources :leads`.

Comment: the option `method: :patch` is given as arg to the `lead_path` method, it should be passed to the `link_to` : `<%= link_to loan_product, lead_path(@lead, lead: { loan_product: loan_product }), method: :patch %>
`

Comment: Ah, thank-you! That was a frustrating hour, ha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in my comment:

the option `method: :patch` is given as arg to the `lead_path` method, it should be passed to the `link_to` instead:

```
<%= link_to loan_product, lead_path(...), method: :patch %>
```